# Surjectivity of p-adic logarithm

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Suppose $\log_p:\mathbb{C}_p^*\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}_p$ is a extension of the standard p-adic logarithm. How does one show that it's surjective?

Comment: Please define what an "extension" of the $p$-adic logarithm is in this context: Is the original log given by a power series on $1+p \mathbb Z_p$? Or on $\{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x-1\rvert_p < 1\}$? What do you know about these? Please give context on what you already know about $p$-adic logarithms, what properties such "extension" should have, and what your thoughts on the problem are. (Also, I guess $\mathbb C$ should be $\mathbb C_p$.)

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/278399/27465. Also, if it comes down to investigating surjectivity of the power series on its disk of convergence in $\mathbb C_p$, take a look at the argument in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4318424/96384.

Comment: Easy to see that $\log_p(x)=-\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(1-x)^n}{n}$ (limit in $\Bbb{C}_p$) is surjective from $\{ b\in \Bbb{C}_p,|1-b|_p< 1\} $ to $ \Bbb{C}_p$: given $a\in \Bbb{C}_p$ take $k$ such that $|ap^k|_p < |p^2|_p$, let $b=\exp_p(ap^k)$ so that $\log_p(b)=ap^k$ then $\log_p(b^{1/p^k})=\frac1{p^k}\log_p(b) = a$. If it isn't what you asked for then please clarify your question.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thanks for the remarks, I've now edited the question.

Comment: @reuns, thanks, this is exactly what I've asked for.